# In google sheets, when the value of a cell is "hold" it turns strangely green

Tags: google-sheets

Open a new google sheet and type the word "hold" into a cell and it turns green like this:

[image]

even if you make it a formula, or all upper case, whenever the result in the field ends up being "hold" it turns strangely green like that!

What is this?
How can this be turned off?

Comment: The best (and often only) way the get help on something this specific is to share a link to the sheet, being sure to set the link's Share permissions (when creating the link) to "Anyone with the link..." and "Editor" so that those here can actually access the sheet fully. Off the top of my head, is it possible that you have a conditional formatting rule in play for this sheet/range?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That green box usually indicates that there's a search going on through "Ctrl + F", Make sure there isn't an active search going on, not sure why it would be there for any other reason.